# Starting task manager programmatically on Windows 8

Tags: windows, taskmanager

I need to start the task manager from within Windows 8 programmatically.

On pre-Windows 8 I simply used something like that:

```
Dim sPath$
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
sPath = fso.GetSpecialFolder(1)
sPath = sPath & "\taskmgr.exe"
Shell(sPath)
```

Actually the programming language does not really matter.

The thing seems to be that there is no longer taskmgr.exe on a Windows 8 system.

Did anybody find out how to start the task manager anyway?

I am not talking about bring the selection window up, I would like to open up the task manager right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task manager is still there, in Windows 8.  See for example [this article](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/3422276/how-use-windows-8-task-manager/) about the Windows 8 task manager.

Answer (score 0):

you can probably analyze the return code to Shell() function call. It may help you to get the exact issue.